# How to increase deployment timeout for openshift nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, git, deployment, openshift

When I do `git push` and `rhc tail <appname>` in other terminal I can see that my server still does not start, but I have `Application '<appname>' failed to start (port 8080 not available)` in `git push` output.
When I use no-scaling app it wasn't a problem – all working good, but now, with scalable app I should manually restart `haproxy` after my server started (I can see it by `rhc tail`).

I know that solution present, at least for JBoss applications. It's [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/troubleshooting-faq.html#_why_is_my_jboss_application_timing_out). But **can** I use it for my case or else **what** I should use?

Thanks for your attention.